# Add dictionary values to a set in python

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I'm new to python. I have a dictionary with subsets as values, link this:

```
dict = {key1: [value1, value2, value 3], key2: [value4], key3: [value5, value6]}
```

and so on.

I would like to store some of the sub-sets of values in a new set. For instance, I would like to merge values from key1 and key3 so to have

```
set1 = [value1, value2, value 3,value5, value6]
```

I've tried to do something like this:

```
d1= set()
d1.add(dict['key1'])
d1.add(dict['key3'])
```

but it does not seem to work (I get the error TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'). Any help?

Comment: Is it showing any errors?

Comment: @Babu: yes, I've added it in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d1= set()
map(d1.add, dict['key1'])
map(d1.add, dict['key3'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You must coerce each list to a set before trying to join their values:

```
>>> set(dict["key1"]) | set(dict["key3"])
{'value 3', 'value1', 'value2', 'value5', 'value6'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using comprehension:

```
new_set = {v for v_list in dict.values() for v in v_list}
```